# MySQL procedure: error in fetch

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling, cursor, runtime-error

I'm having this issue. I'm using MySQL 5.7.10

I have defined this PL (I know, the debug messages in TRAZAS table are a bit scrappy):

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS my_proc;
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(... , OUT resultado INT, OUT mensaje TEXT)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE sqlstate_code VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE message_text TEXT;
    DECLARE mysql_errno INT;

    DECLARE v_id_cliente VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE v_device VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE v_fecha_solicitud_crm DATETIME;
    DECLARE v_id_ciclo VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE v_fecha_alta DATETIME;
    DECLARE v_fecha_baja DATETIME;
    DECLARE v_fecha_alta_promocion DATETIME;


    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;


    DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
    select id_cliente, device, fecha_solicitud_crm, id_ciclo,
        min(FECHAS.fecha_inicio) AS FECHA_INICIO, max(FECHAS.fecha_fin) AS FECHA_FIN
    from xxx
    where 
        xxx
    GROUP BY xxx
    ORDER BY xxx;


    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        SET resultado = 1;

        START TRANSACTION;      
        INSERT INTO TRAZAS(TEXTO) VALUES (concat_ws(' - ', 'ERROR my_proc'));
        COMMIT;

        get diagnostics condition 1 message_text = MESSAGE_TEXT, sqlstate_code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, mysql_errno = MYSQL_ERRNO;
        SET mensaje = concat_ws(' - ', sqlstate_code, mysql_errno, message_text);

        START TRANSACTION;      
        INSERT INTO TRAZAS(TEXTO) VALUES (concat_ws(' - ', 'ERROR my_proc', mensaje));
        COMMIT;

    END;

    SET resultado = 0;
    SET mensaje = '';




    OPEN my_cursor;

    /* Inicio del bucle */
    read_loop: LOOP

        START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO TRAZAS(TEXTO) VALUES ('Inicio del loop. Antes del fetch');
        COMMIT;


        FETCH my_cursor INTO v_id_cliente, v_device, v_fecha_solicitud_crm, v_id_ciclo, v_fecha_alta, v_fecha_baja;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;


        START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO TRAZAS(TEXTO) VALUES ('Despues del fetch');
        COMMIT;


        /*****/
        START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO TRAZAS(TEXTO) VALUES (concat_ws(' - ', 'my_proc', 'v_id_cliente', v_id_cliente));
        INSERT INTO TRAZAS(TEXTO) VALUES (concat_ws(' - ', 'my_proc', 'v_device', v_device));
        INSERT INTO TRAZAS(TEXTO) VALUES (concat_ws(' - ', 'my_proc', 'v_fecha_solicitud_crm', v_fecha_solicitud_crm));
        INSERT INTO TRAZAS(TEXTO) VALUES (concat_ws(' - ', 'my_proc', 'v_fecha_alta', v_fecha_alta));
        INSERT INTO TRAZAS(TEXTO) VALUES (concat_ws(' - ', 'my_proc', 'v_fecha_baja', v_fecha_baja));
        COMMIT;
        /*****/


        /*
        Stuff with fetched data
        */


        START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO TRAZAS(TEXTO) VALUES ('Siguiente iteracion del loop');
        COMMIT;


    /* Fin del bucle */
    END LOOP read_loop;

    CLOSE my_cursor;

END$
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm sure cursor select fetch 6 rows. I run that query with the same PL input data in HeidiSQL, and it fetch 6 rows.

Also, I'm sure thath any field in the 6 rows is null or blank. All data are fulfilled.

Unfortunately, the cursor only returns 1 row.
The current behaviour is:

- First row is fetched and processed. Stuff is done right.
  [image: First row image]
- Second row only shows the 'Inicio del loop. Antes del fetch' message. Second message ('Despues del fetch') is not shown.

[image: Second row image]

- When retrieving result and exit message with select @resultado, @mensaje ,  it shows 0 and blank.

[image: Zero resultado]

So, it seems that there is an error in the native FETCH sentence, but I can't get any info about the error with 'get diagnostics', HeidiSQL does not show anything...

I'm stuck in this point. Any help is very appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**: Here are the actual data retrieved by cursor query in HeidiSQL:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id_cliente`, `device`, `fecha_solicitud_crm`, `id_ciclo`, `FECHA_INICIO`, `FECHA_FIN`) VALUES ('cod1-6a00-43b6-86ad-1234567e551', '60601234567533098', '2017-08-17', 'C14', '2017-07-02 05:00:22', '2017-07-21 05:55:03');
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id_cliente`, `device`, `fecha_solicitud_crm`, `id_ciclo`, `FECHA_INICIO`, `FECHA_FIN`) VALUES ('cod2-25d3-4282-a471-12345672806', '60601234567516069', '2017-08-17', 'C14', '2017-02-19 07:03:47', '2017-07-19 07:55:02');
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id_cliente`, `device`, `fecha_solicitud_crm`, `id_ciclo`, `FECHA_INICIO`, `FECHA_FIN`) VALUES ('cod3-c07d-42cd-9b23-12345671c2e', '60601234567605474', '2017-08-17', 'C14', '2017-06-29 05:40:17', '2017-07-27 05:05:02');
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id_cliente`, `device`, `fecha_solicitud_crm`, `id_ciclo`, `FECHA_INICIO`, `FECHA_FIN`) VALUES ('cod4-aafe-4442-a429-12345679312', '60601234567543931', '2017-08-17', 'C14', '2017-06-24 05:22:24', '2017-07-19 07:55:02');
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id_cliente`, `device`, `fecha_solicitud_crm`, `id_ciclo`, `FECHA_INICIO`, `FECHA_FIN`) VALUES ('cod5-0408-4656-84de-12345676ea5', '60601234567537024', '2017-08-17', 'C14', '2017-04-04 08:17:27', '2017-07-23 05:05:01');
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id_cliente`, `device`, `fecha_solicitud_crm`, `id_ciclo`, `FECHA_INICIO`, `FECHA_FIN`) VALUES ('cod6-b1e2-4192-8f33-12345676ac1', '60601234567520152', '2017-08-17', 'C14', '2017-04-30 07:03:09', '2017-07-25 05:05:02');
```

Comment: Do you have sample data that you can post?. It would make it easier to determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hPNn1rnwRaru9KaW7K2nKi/0).

Comment: @wchiquito, thanks a lot for your answer. I have posted actual data retrieved by the query (I have updated the main post).

Comment: Can you post the complete query used to construct the cursor?. I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hPNn1rnwRaru9KaW7K2nKi/1).

Comment: @wchiquito, thanks again. I have updated the db-fiddle. There is an error, but maybe is because of the adaptation to the fiddle. I don't know.

Comment: Be careful with the uppercase and lowercase letters in your tables and columns., see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hPNn1rnwRaru9KaW7K2nKi/7).

Comment: @wchiquito, thanks again. I'll try on this, maybe something in the stuff is wrong or maybe the runtime query in the actual environment does not retrieve as many rows as I expect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fixed my PL.

Maybe, there is something in the stuff that makes the cursor doesn't work, but I can't proof it.

So, finally, I have splitted it into two PLs

- On the first PL, the cursor is declared and retrieve all rows.
- Then, the second PL is invoked for each row and makes all the stuff.

It's rare, but now it works.

Hope it helps. Thanks.